# Spike removal algorithm

Tags: objective-c, c, algorithm

I have an array of values ranging from 30 to 300. I want to somehow make an weighted average, where, if I have 5 values and one is a lot bigger than the rest(spike), it won't influence the average that much as it would if I simply make a arithmetic average: eg: `(n1+n2+n3+n4+n5)/5`.

Does anyone has an idea how to make an simple algorithm that does just that, or where to look?

Comment: Hmmm ... `(n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 - min5(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) - max5(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)) / 3` ???

Comment: You can also consider using a geometric mean.  However, this will be sensitive to "inverse spikes" (much lower values).

Comment: that simply removes the spike, it has no weight in the average, is like : (n1 + n2 + n3)/3 where n4 and n5 are minimum and maximum. I would like to find something in which even the spikes have a weight in the average, small one, but if I have 7 spikes in 100 values, should influence it a bit. Makes sense?

Comment: I wonder how big is the intersection of StackOverflow users and James Taranto readers.

Comment: Apparently that set has at least 2 members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to discard data that falls outside some parameter range you've specified. You could do it by computing the median/mode and ignoring values outside of this range when computing your mean. You'll have to adjust the divisor accordingly, of course, to account for the number of discarded values. What this "tolerable" range should be is ultimately up to you to decide, and will likely depend on your specific application needs.

Alternatively, you could try something like eliminating items r% out of range of your total average. Something like this (in javascript):

```
function RangedAverage(arr, r)
{
    x = Average(arr);
    //now eliminate items r% out of range
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        if(arr[i] < (x/r) || arr[i]>(x*(1+r)))
            arr.splice(i,1);
    x = Average(arr); //compute new average
    return x;
}
```

Comment: This looks great, and is simple enough for the intended use. Will try it right away!

Comment: A slight correction about my code comments, r should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @mindnoise I don't understand. You said you wanted those "spikes" to still count a little. In this case you're still throwing out the spikes? Well you could argue that the spikes helped determine the average which we used in determining which to eliminate, but are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: The truth is I changed a little the code, but this was the base code and so I choose it as the correct answer. Sorry I didn't mention it. Instead of removing the spikes, I "averaged" them based on how much they were out of the chart(and removed them for good if above a certain value).

Comment: any chance you can post the code to you solution mindnoise.  i dont see how you the above solution would work for a dataset like 1,1,1,200 as it would eliminate all values before doing the final average

Comment: I think there's a mistake here. It should be `if(arr[i] < (x*r) || arr[i]>(x*(1+r)))` because `x*r` returns the r% value if r is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a [*median filter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) rather than a *mean filter*.  It's often used in image processing to mitigate spurious pixel values (as opposed to white noise).

Comment: Thanks for the link, will have a look, I really didn't knew how to search it.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed the mean is susceptible to skewing by spikes. perhaps median or mode may be a better statistic as they tend to be less skewed?

this should be a comment but js seems to be broken for me atm: its not quite clear whether you are after a single number that is characteristic of your array (i.e. an average) or a new array with the spikes removed (median filter)

in response to that then i'd suggest you first look at if median or mode is more appropriate as a statistic. if not then apply a median filter (very good at removing spikes) then average

Comment: I'm after a single number that is characteristic of my array ;)

Answer (score 0):

A [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) is often used in similar applications.  I don't know if it qualifies as "simple," but it's robust and well known.

Comment: A Kalman filter would need a lot of assumptions on the data, and most of them would be incompatible with large spikes. A Kalman filter will "follow" the spikes, instead of removing them.

Comment: Agreed.  A Kalman filter doesn't sound appropriate here; not only would it need an accurate model of the underlying process, but more fundamentally it's used for recovering a process from Gaussian *white* (or coloured) noise, not spurious spikes.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways of doing this: You could implement a [low-pass digital filter.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_pass_filter)

Or, if you're just concerned about removing outliers from a statistical summary, you could just remove the highest and lowest N% of your data values from the dataset before averaging.

Comment: A moving-average *is* a low-pass digital filter.  You will really need non-linear processing to eliminate spurious spikes.

Answer (score 0):

"Robust statistics" is the search term that will get you into the literature. An advantage of a Kalman filter is that you have a running estimate of the variability of the data, and this allows you eventually to "discard observations that are more than x% likely to be spurious given the whole set of observations so far".